# Mono for Android for VS 2012

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2012

I am working on VS 2012 Express and I want to get into Android Dev with Mono for Android (or Xamarin as it is now called I think).

How do I install it for my VS 2012?

I tried the download page on the Xamarin site but that installs VS itself with Xamarin.

Comment: You should use VS 2015.

Comment: Better yet, you should use VS 2017. https://www.visualstudio.com/xamarin/ VS 2015 and above is required: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#windows

Answer (score 0):

You just go to Tools-->Extentions and Updates--> typing Xamarin and install ( get xamarin and Xamarin for visual studio